# extremely slow website, pingdom pagespeed score 92, wait time is high

Tags: wordpress, apache, performance, server, pagespeed

We are bulding an ecommerce website on wordpress. The test server is of Amazon and the website was hosted on VPS server of godaddy. It used to take 15 s to load on VPS whereas amazon server was taking around 7-8 S. We wanted to bring it down to less than 3 S per page. As the VPS server was slow, we shifted it to dedicated server of hostgator.

The change results in positives like pagespeed score on pingdom tools increased above 90, it was 60 on amazon test server and godaddy VPS earlier. As per google pagespeed results, the new server is excellent and has waiting time of less than 0.4 S. For VPS godaddy it used to be 5 S and amazon it is 2 S.

Here's the problem : 
Surprisingly, the time for the pages to load has increased to 50S - 60 S now. It is observed that main issue is the wait time per request.

(Note : Time to load first byte was always the problem. It has always been around 50% of total load time for the page. e.g. 7-8 S for godaddy, 2-3 S for amazon and currently 30 S for hostgator. So, i know it is a problem but nothing new in it. 60 S load time on dedicated server is unbelievable and I am not able to locate where and what is going wrong.)

Please help !

Comment: This could be a hosting issue or an issue with your ecommerce plugin. Also it could be a problem with your settings. More information is needed to solve this. Try to use the general optimization plugins: wpsuperache, autoptimize, image tools like: lazyload or tinypng.